# environment variable use in Cloudflare workers node.js

Tags: cloudflare-workers

I saw many articles setting environment variables in Cloudflare workers. but I am not able to read or retrieve it in node.js
Code:

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
  if ('OKOK' == process.env.API_KEY) {
    return new Response('found', {
      headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain' },
    })
  }
}
```

[image]

wrangler.toml

```
name = "hello"
type = "javascript"

# account_id = ""
workers_dev = true
[env.production]
name = "API_KEY"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Cloudflare Workers does not use Node.js. In Workers, environment variables become simple globals. So, to access your environment variable, you would just write `API_KEY`, not `process.env.API_KEY`.

(Note: Workers is currently transitioning to a new syntax based on ES modules. In that syntax, environment variables work differently; an `env` object is passed to the event handler containing all variables. Most people aren't using this new syntax yet, though. You would know if you are using it if your JavaScript uses `export default {` to define event handlers; on the other hand, if it uses `addEventListener("fetch", ...)`, then it is using the old syntax.)

Comment: is this same for environment variable secret(encrypt) and will it will secure for storing secure keys

Comment: how to use env in .json file

Comment: Outdated solution

Comment: @VityaSchel why do you say that? Still looks correct to me.

Comment: Definitely still correct approach for this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you use Miniflare now, pretty easy and strenght forward

```
"start": "miniflare --watch --debug -e .env"
```

This is an official Cloudflare lib by the way:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/miniflare

Reasone:
Miniflare is a simulator for developing and testing Cloudflare Workers.

> Fun: develop workers easily with detailed logging, file watching
> and pretty error pages supporting source maps.
>
> Full-featured: supports most Workers features, including KV,
> Durable Objects, WebSockets, modules and more.
>
> ⚡ Fully-local: test and develop Workers without an internet
> connection. Reload code on change quickly. It's an alternative to
> wrangler dev, written in TypeScript, that runs your workers in a
> sandbox implementing Workers' runtime APIs.

Answer (score 0):

If the usage format is this: `addEventListener("fetch", ...)`
In your worker.js, you just would write(`API_KEY`), example:

```
async function handleRequest(request) {
 if ('OKOK' == API_KEY) {
  return new Response('found', {
   headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain' },
  })
 }
}
```